# How Can I Export Scraped Data to Excel Horizontally?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to Python. Using this site as an example, I'm trying to scrape the restaurants' information but I'm not sure how to pivot this data horizontally when it's being read vertically. I'd like the Excel sheet to have six columns as follows: Name, Street, City, State, Zip, Phone. This is the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get('https://www.restaurant.com/listing?&&st=KS&p=KS&p=PA&page=1&&searchradius=50&loc=10021')
time.sleep(10)
with urlopen(driver.current_url) as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    pageList = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": {"details"}})
    list_of_inner_text = [x.text for x in pageList]
    text = ', '.join(list_of_inner_text)
    print(text)
```

Thanks

EDIT: Based on feedback, here's what I would expect from the first five restaurants on this page:
[FirstFiveRestaurants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv3RL.png)

Comment: Perhaps show first few rows of desired output. urllib.request is also not needed as you want to work with driver.page_source in BeautifulSoup. What you are retrieving currently includes a lot of unwanted material (I think) so seeing expected output would help.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, I've added an image for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way. You mileage may vary on other pages.

This line

```
details = [re.sub(r'\s{2,}|[,]', '',i) for i in restuarant.select_one('h3 + p').text.strip().split('\n') if i!=''
```

basically handles the generation of the output columns (bar name) by splitting the `p` tag on '\n' and doing a little string cleaning.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Documents\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.restaurant.com/listing?&&st=KS&p=KS&p=PA&page=1&&searchradius=50&loc=10021')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".restaurants")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
restuarants = soup.select('.restaurants')
results = []

for restuarant in restuarants:
    details = [re.sub(r'\s{2,}|[,]', '',i) for i in restuarant.select_one('h3 + p').text.strip().split('\n') if i!='']
    details.insert(0, restuarant.select_one('h3 a').text)
    results.append(details)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns= ['Name','Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Phone'])
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

[image]